# BibLaTeX: Lists by multiple fields of same type?

Tags: biblatex

Is there a way to construct lists by multiple instances of a field instead of using `and` or comma, respectively?

E.g.,
instead of

```
@article{FooBar,
   ...
   author = {John Doe and Richard Roe},
   keywords={foo, bar},
   ...
}
```

I would like to get the same result in the reference by

```
@article{FooBar,
   ...
   author = {John Doe},
   author = {Richard Roe},
   keyword={foo},
   keyword={bar},
   ...
}
```

Comment: This can't be done. You have to obey the syntax and semantics of the bibtex .bib language and this "multiple field" style doesn't exist in bibtex. The only way around this is to pre-processs your .bib syntactically with a script.

Comment: @PLK: Thank you, I’ve suspected so. However, since my approach actually obeys the syntax and BibLaTeX allows for several semantically manipulations, I was hoping for a possiblility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can't be done. You have to obey the syntax and semantics of the bibtex .bib language and this "multiple field" style doesn't exist in bibtex. The only way around this is to pre-processs your .bib syntactically with a script.